# Is there any way to have events with a variable in Java? Example inside

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, queue, runnable

Say, I have a SystemQueue class that wraps a Queue object. I add to this queue using systemQueue.add(whatever), and I have a different object thats a Runnable that checks the queue, and if its not empty, takes from the queue and uses "whatever" in its code. Is there any way to do this besides having an infinite loop in the run like

```
    run(){
        while(true){
            if(!systemQueue.isEmpty()){
                  todo
             }
       }
   }
```

and have that run forever?
What I'm asking is, how can I code using event-based-coding in java?

Is there any way I can add an eventListener to the queue inside SystemQueue, and if the queue changes, call out to SystemExecutor and have it run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Queue` itself doesn't provide that option. You can implement your own listener/event pair though.

Event:

```
public class SystemEvent extends java.util.EventObject{
    public SystemEvent(SystemQueue src){
        super(src);
    }

    public SystemQueue getSource(){
         return (SystemQueue) super.getSource();
    }
}
```

Listener:

```
public interface SystemListener extends java.util.EventListener{
    public void eventQueued(SystemEvent e);
}
```

in SystemQueue:

```
ArrayList<SystemListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

protected void fireEventQueued(){
    SystemEvent e = new SystemEvent(this);

    listeners.forEach(l -> l.eventQueued(e));
}

public void addSystemListener(SystemListener l){
     listeners.add(l);
}

public void add(something){
    //add something
    fireEventQueued();
}
```

Now all you need to do is make SystemExecutor implement `SystemListener` and add the instance as listener.

Comment: I think I explained it a bad way. Its basically a chat program. When say, a message is received, a ChatMessage is created and put in to the OutputQueue. Now, Theres a ChatExecutor which checks OutputQueue constantly and when it's not empty, starts taking and sending them through the ClientManager which then sends it out to all the streams connected. I am trying to extend my ChatMessage class, but it's telling me it can't since theres a parameter in my constructor, which is the UUID, which I need to be final. I mean, it doesn't have to be, but I like it to be.. I can use a builder pattern...

Comment: Also, this message will be going in to the InputQueue, as a Message, then InputQueueSorter takes it, finds out if its a command, or a chat message, and builds either a SystemMessage or ChatMessage, and puts them in to SystemQueue or OutputQueue, respectively.

Comment: If you don't need busy waiting then you need to implement the observer pattern which Paul tried to explain in his code. All the streams are consumers where your ChatExecutor will be the producer. Builder pattern does not match your use case.

Comment: I just did it this way, github link https://github.com/CjStaal/Chatroom-v2-Server/tree/master/src/main/java/com/staalcomputingsolutions/chatroom/server/messaging

Comment: as far as i understand the code you're just at the same point again. you'll wind up with a single thread and an endless loop.

Comment: @paul , yeah, I know. The issue with the observer pattern described in the answer is that why even have a queue? If it's firing from the add, then why not just pass it directly to the consumer?